# Hyper-V limit disk usage of a VM

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, performance

I'm using Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I have one virtual machine that writes constantly to its vhd, using between 60% and 100% of the maximum disk I/O according to Resource Monitor.  This makes other VMs on that server very slow.

This VM is doing useful work so I don't want to shut it down.  Is there any way in Hyper-V limit the amount of disk I/O? Or reduce the priority of that VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will either need to change your storage. Whether it is a faster disk, or separate the .vhd to another spindle entirely, or make it a physical server.